# Flexbox working in Safari on some sections of my site and not in others

Tags: safari, flexbox

Im a fairly new designer and I redesigned my website using flexbox. It is rendering correctly in other browsers i.e. Chrome, IE, FireFox due to some slight hacks. In Safari some of the sections are rendering as expected and some are not distributing space properly. I have tried everything I can think of and cannot figure out a fix that does not break the layout in other browsers. Any suggestions? Below is the code for one of the sections not working...

```
<section class="flex-container">
    <header>
    <div class="header1">
     <img id="profile" src="images/profile.png" width="250px">
    <h1>content</h1>
    <h2>content</h2>
        </div>
    <div class="header2">
    <ul class="socialmedia">
        <li class="sm-icon1"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/danielthecre8r/"><img src="images/facebook_icon.png"></a></li>
        <li class="sm-icon2"><a href="https://twitter.com/danielthecre8r"><img src="images/twitter_icon.png"></a></li>
        <li class="sm-icon3"><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/danielthecre8r"><img src="images/linkedin_icon.png"></a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </header>
    </section>


.flex-container {
display: -webkit-box;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
-webkit-box-direction: normal;
-webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
        flex-direction: column;
}

/* Landing Styles */

header {
height: 1000px;
background: url(images/landing_background2.png) center no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
display: -webkit-box;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
-webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
-webkit-box-direction: normal;
-webkit-flex-direction: row;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
        flex-direction: row;
-webkit-box-align: center;
-webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
        align-items: center;

}

.header1 {
display: -webkit-box;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
-webkit-flex: 10 1 600px;
flex: 10 1 600px;
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
-webkit-box-direction: normal;
-webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
        flex-direction: column;
-webkit-justify-content: space-around;
    -ms-flex-pack: distribute;
        justify-content: space-around;
-webkit-box-align: center;
-webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
        align-items: center;


}

.header2 {
height: 300px;
-webkit-flex: 1 1 1px;
flex: 1 1 1px;
display: -webkit-box;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
margin-right: 20px;

}

.header2 ul {
display: -webkit-box;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
-webkit-box-direction: normal;
-webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
        flex-direction: column;
-webkit-box-pack: justify;
-webkit-justify-content: space-between;
    -ms-flex-pack: justify;
        justify-content: space-between;

}
header h1 {
text-align: center;
font-size: 500%;
}

header h2 {
text-align: center;
font-family: "Merriweather", serif;
font-size: 150%;
letter-spacing: .1em;

}
```

The way it is rendering in Safari looks like `.header1` and `.header2` are coded to `flex-direction: row; flex: 1 1 auto; justify-content: flex-start;` against each other at the left side of the page.